# Inserting an item with a specific color in a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to insert items in a listbox, but I want to color the text of specific items, depending on an integer. How can I insert an item with a specific color in the listbox ?

Thanks!

Comment: `Winform` \ `Asp.net` \ `WPF` ... What?

Comment: Windows FORM application

Comment: I added the `tag` for it

Comment: is it winforms or web applicaiton ?

Comment: try this [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/b145eecc-9ee2-47b7-8e45-0bf32396473d/](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/b145eecc-9ee2-47b7-8e45-0bf32396473d/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed of your Listbox control. and associate listBox_DrawItem event handler to it [listbox draw item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx)

```
private void listBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    Graphics yourObj = e.Graphics;

    yourObj .FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), e.Bounds);

    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to change the forecolor of items, not the background color.

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

A `ListBox` Item can be a object of any type. That means you cant set the color for a ListBox item at the moment you add them.

You need the `DrawItem` event.

> **ListBox.DrawItem Event**  Occurs when a visual aspect of an owner-drawn ListBox changes.

#### Sample

```
private void lstBox_DrawItem(object sender, _
      System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
//
// Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
// Create a new Brush and initialize to a Black colored brush
// by default.
//
e.DrawBackground();
Brush myBrush = Brushes.Black;
//
// Determine the color of the brush to draw each item based on 
// the index of the item to draw.
//
switch (e.Index)
{
    case 0:
        myBrush = Brushes.Red;
        break;
    case 1:
        myBrush = Brushes.Orange;
        break;
    case 2:
        myBrush = Brushes.Purple;
        break;
}
//
// Draw the current item text based on the current 
// Font and the custom brush settings.
//
e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(), 
    e.Font, myBrush,e.Bounds,StringFormat.GenericDefault);
//
// If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle 
// around the selected item.
//
e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

#### More Information

- [Change the Color of Individual .Net ListBox items](http://www.thescarms.com/dotNet/CustomListBox.aspx)
- [ListBox.DrawItem Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will give you some idea...

```
                listView1.Items.Clear();
                int k = 0;
                foreach (Player p in players)
                {
                    ListViewItem lvitem = new ListViewItem();
                    lvitem.Text = p.name;
                    lvitem.BackColor = p.color;
                    listView1.Items.Add(lvitem);

                    k++;
                }
```

Player is the class. It has name and color.

Comment: This did not work for me.  It did not change the colors.